# How to integrate sharepoint web part?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am new to SharePoint development.

I have download a '.wsp' file which resides in `C:\SlideShow.wsp` I want to use this file in my site as web part. I searched over the internet to integrate it and found many solution to do so through power shell script using the command.. `Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath` but it is not working in my case.

I executed this commannd `Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "C:\SlideShow.wsp" but it gives error..

How do I integrate it?

Please help.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com ???

Answer (score 0):

Go under the Page where you want to add it: `Settings->Site Settings->Solutions->Upload Solution`

Or with Powershell

Make sure:

- Started SharePoint 2010 Manangement Console
- Started it as Administrator

For Farm solutions use:
Add-SPSolution C:\SlideShow.wsp

For Sandbox solutions use: 
Add-SPUserSolution C:\SlideShow.wsp

Comment: I uploaded the solution.. but when edited the page and under the Insert->WebPart ribbon I am not finding the uploaded solution.

Comment: after the upload you have to activate the solution. Did you do that?

Comment: I activated the solution but still not finding it any categories of web part in Insert-> Web Part menu. @Mark

Answer (score 0):

As Mark says you have to enable web part from Site collection Features , But it should be automatically enabled , FYI whenever creating a web part in VS2010 please check that you are referencing your web part to SP2010 site other wise SP will not consider it in its trusted zone(Safe Control) , If you are still unable to locate your web part  register your DLL in GAC . Sharepoint will consider it as a Safe control .
--Sorry for short answer ,,Please let me know if it works .